# How to quickly create multiple Drupal 7 features?

Tags: 7, features

I use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) to manage configuration of my Drupal 7 systems.

Until now I was creating features manually but even with [Features Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ftools) installed and ajax features status disabled it is a mundane process.

I want a separate feature for each contrib module and a separate feature for each view.

Is there a way to create features automatically or at least more quickly, maybe using [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Drush features add/export commands (add was removed in the latest version of Features (rc1)).  As there have been a lot of changes recently with features rc1 and drush 5.0, the exact commands will differ depending on your setup, but `drush help` will list the features commands and `drush help fe` will show you the details (in this case, how to export [e.g., create] a feature).

If you really needed to create a lot of features, you could script Drush (either extend Drush itself or run Drush via bash script, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I will try drush fe as you suggested. Good point, I also pack drush commands into bash scripts. I just didn't use drush & features integration until now.